# Lower bound for product is a constant?

Tags: inner-products

Assume $c>0$.

I showed that
$$
\langle x,x\rangle\geqslant D \exp\Big(-\frac{c}{2}z\Big)
$$
and
$$
\langle y,y\rangle\geqslant D\exp\Big(\frac{c}{2}z\Big).
$$
for some constant $D>0$.

Does this mean that
$$
\langle x,x\rangle \langle y,y\rangle\geqslant D^2 \exp(0)=D^2, 
$$

i.e. the product has a constant positive lower bound?

Comment: You can multiply inequalities (if all expressions are non-negative). Is that what  you are asking for?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\langle x,x\rangle \ge 0$, we have
$$
\langle x,x\rangle \langle y,y\rangle\geqslant \langle x,x\rangle D\exp(\frac{c} {2}z) \ge D \exp(-\frac{c}{2}z)D\exp(\frac{c} {2}z) = D^2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $D^2$ is a constant positive lower bound.